# Responsive login bar

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, responsive

I'm facing an annoying issue. I'm trying to make my web app responsive and I'm almost done, only left to make the login bar responsive and that is a big problem for me. I tried some stuff but it all looks messy and ugly. I can't make it look the way I want, hope someone here could help out.

My code:

```css
.container {
  width: 85%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  background-color: #262626;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 20px;
  min-height: 70px;
}

header a {
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

header a:hover {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-color: #2a2a2a;
  color: #D52B1E;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
}

header li {
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

header #logo {
  float: left;
}

#logo a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#login {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#login .container .wellcome-user-left {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#login .container .logout-right {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#login .container .login-info {
  float: center;
}

#login .container select {
  width: 10%;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: none;
}

#login .container input[type="text"],
[type="password"] {
  width: 10%;
  font-size: 12px;
  transition: 0.6s;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  background-color: white;
  transition: 0.2s;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 6px 16px;
}

#login .container input[type="text"],
[type="password"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#login .container button[type="submit"] {
  width: 6%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s;
  padding: 6px 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

#login .container button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #D52B1E;
  color: white;
}

#login .container .logout-btn {
  background-color: white;
  color: #262626;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 6px 14px;
}

#login .container .logout-btn:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #262626;
}

@media(max-width: 736px) {
  header #logo,
  header nav,
  header nav li {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #login .container .login-info {
    float: right;
    font-size: 8px;
  }
  #login {
    float: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  #login .container .login-info button[type="submit"] {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s;
  }
  #login .container .login-info button[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #D52B1E;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="login">

  <div class="container" style="width:100%">
    <div class="wellcome-user-left">

      <ul>
        <li *ngIf="showLogin">Hello&nbsp;<b>{{username}} </b>, &nbsp;please log in</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li *ngIf="!showLogin">Wellcome&nbsp;<b>{{username}} </b>, &nbsp;enjoy</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="logout-right" *ngIf="!showLogin">
      <button (click)="logout()" class="logout-btn"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>Logout</button>
    </div>
    <div class="login-info" *ngIf="showLogin">
      <i class="fas fa-user"></i> Username
      <input type="text" placeholder="enter username..." #username>

      <i class="fas fa-key"></i> Password
      <input type="password" placeholder="enter password..." #password>

      <select #cType>
        <option selected hidden>Select Client</option>
        <option>ADMIN</option>
        <option>COMPANY</option>
        <option>CUSTOMER</option>
      </select>

      <button type="submit" (click)="loginUser(username,password,cType)">LOGIN</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

My result is this:

[image: how it looks like]

And this is how I wish it was:

[image: how I wish it was]

Update after editing:(after TsaiKoga help)
[update after @TsaiKoga help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRrHv.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the username, password and select fields need to be nested in each 'div', then you can control all this input fields by 'div' display inline or block when they are responsive or not.

You can try this(ps: you can fix some style that you need):

```css
    .container {
      width: 85%;
      margin: auto;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    header {
      background-color: #262626;
      color: white;
      padding-top: 20px;
      min-height: 70px;
    }

    header a {
      letter-spacing: 1.5px;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 8px 16px;
    }

    header a:hover {
      padding: 8px 16px;
      border-color: #2a2a2a;
      color: #D52B1E;
      letter-spacing: 1.5px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      outline: none;
      display: block;
    }

    header li {
      padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
      display: inline-flex;
    }

    header #logo {
      float: left;
    }

    #logo a {
      color: white;
      display: block;
      font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: none;
      font-size: 25px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    header nav {
      float: right;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }

    #login {
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 30px;
      background-color: #f4f4f4;
      color: black;
      font-size: 12px;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    #login .container .wellcome-user-left {
      float: left;
      margin-top: 5px;
    }

    #login .container .logout-right {
      float: right;
      margin-top: 5px;
    }

    #login .container .login-info {
      float: center;
    }

    #login .container select {
      width: 60%;
      font-size: 12px;
      margin-left: 20px;
      border: none;
    }
    #login .login-field-container {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    #login .login-field-container .login-field {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    #login .login-btn {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    #login .container input[type="text"],
    [type="password"] {
      width: 50%;
      font-size: 12px;
      transition: 0.6s;
      border: 1px solid #cacaca;
      background-color: white;
      transition: 0.2s;
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      padding: 6px 16px;
    }

    #login .container input[type="text"],
    [type="password"]:focus {
      outline: none;
    }

    #login .container button[type="submit"] {
      width: 6%;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      background: transparent;
      color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: 0.2s;
      padding: 6px 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 12px;
      margin-left: 25px;
    }

    #login .container button[type="submit"]:hover {
      background: #D52B1E;
      color: white;
    }

    #login .container .logout-btn {
      background-color: white;
      color: #262626;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 6px 14px;
    }

    #login .container .logout-btn:hover {
      color: white;
      background-color: #262626;
    }

    @media(max-width: 736px) {
      header #logo,
      header nav,
      header nav li {
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
      }
      #login .container .login-info {
        font-size: 8px;
        clear: both;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
      }
      #login {
        float: center;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
        color: black;
        font-size: 10px;
        text-align: left;
      }
      #login .login-field-container {
        height: 100%;
        width: 60%;
        text-align: right;
      }
      #login .login-field-container .login-field {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
      }
      #login .login-btn {
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 30%;
        text-align: left;
      }
      #login .container select {
        margin-right: 10px;
      }
      #login .container .login-info button[type="submit"] {
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        background: transparent;
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.2s;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
      #login .container .login-info button[type="submit"]:hover {
        background: #D52B1E;
        color: white;
      }
    }
```

```html
    <section id="login">

      <div class="container" style="width:100%">
        <div class="wellcome-user-left">

          <ul>
            <li *ngIf="showLogin">Hello&nbsp;<b>{{username}} </b>, &nbsp;please log in</li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li *ngIf="!showLogin">Wellcome&nbsp;<b>{{username}} </b>, &nbsp;enjoy</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="logout-right" *ngIf="!showLogin">
          <button (click)="logout()" class="logout-btn"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>Logout</button>
        </div>

        <div class="login-info" *ngIf="showLogin">

          <div class="login-field-container">
            <div class="login-field">
              <i class="fas fa-user"></i> Username
              <input type="text" placeholder="enter username..." #username>
            </div>

            <div class="login-field">
              <i class="fas fa-key"></i> Password
              <input type="password" placeholder="enter password..." #password>
            </div>

            <div class="login-field">
              <select #cType>
                <option selected hidden>Select Client</option>
                <option>ADMIN</option>
                <option>COMPANY</option>
                <option>CUSTOMER</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="login-btn">
            <button type="submit" (click)="loginUser(username,password,cType)">LOGIN</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
```

Comment: thanks a lot that looks great! only one problem i update the result now in the main post

Comment: I have changed the stylesheets. Hope that will solve your problem.